# MediaPlayer 2 hour mp3 stream, pause after 10 minutes or seekTo is causing Skipped Frames error

Tags: android, audio, mp3

I am trying code my first app, which will play audio files from URL which are about 2 hours long.

I have managed to work and playing great, tested till 30 minutes, but not expecting any issue playing all the way 2 hours.

But If i pause after 10 minutes and start the play again, I am getting Skipped Frames Error

Same is the case with Interactive SeekTo.

I am using Service for MediaPlayer and BroadCast to updated the Progress Bar & Time.

Please the code below.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MP3Service extends Service implements OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnSeekCompleteListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnErrorListener, OnInfoListener 
{

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean playState;
    String mp3Url;
    int seekTo;
    Intent broadCastIntent;

    public MP3Service()
    {

    }

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        Log.v("Mp3 App", "Service On Create");

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);

        broadCastIntent = new Intent("com.example.myfirstapp.SEEKBAR");

      }

      @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v("Mp3 App", "Service On Start");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        mp3Url = (String)extras.get("Mp3URL");
        seekTo = (int)extras.getInt("SeekTo");
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mp3Url);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
      }

      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
          Log.v("Mp3 App", "Service On Completed");
        stopSelf();
      }

      private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
      private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
              //Log.v("Mp3 App", "Runnable Run Method");
              if(playState  && mediaPlayer != null)
              {
                      int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                      broadCastIntent.putExtra("CURRENT_POS", mCurrentPosition);
                      sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent);
                      mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
              }

          }
      };

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("Mp3 App", "Service OnPrepared");
        try {
                playState = true;
                Log.v("Mp3 App", "on Start SeekTo : " + seekTo);
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekTo);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("Mp3 App", "Service OnSeekComplete");
        try {
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            mRunnable.run();
            broadCastIntent.putExtra("DURATION", mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
          Log.v("Mp3 App", "Service On Destroy");
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
          mediaPlayer.stop();
          }
        mediaPlayer.release();
        playState = false;

      }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.v("Mp3 App", "Service OnBufferingUpdate");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("Mp3 App", " -- " + what + "  --  " + extra);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("Mp3 App", " -- " + what + "  --  " + extra);
        return true;
    }



}
```

Let me know if i am doing some thing wrong or I have to change my approach

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I was using SeekTo logic for Pause and Play, now i have used Pause and Start for (Pause/Play) by binding the Service in Activity. This fixes the issue of Pause.   But SeekTo issue still there, will continue my debugging.